# Awk Issue with multiple expression

Tags: awk

Any one can help me what is the issue with below code
back ground :- i have a fixed width file with header , i am trying to count the nulls in the file.
i have a null pattern $col_null_patt=\s , then i am trying to substring the column from file using column start and column_length and trying to do regex match

Issue :-

```
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN {m = ENVIRON["RE"]} c=substr($0,m,p);if($n ~ "^" m "$"{N++} END{print N+0}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                            ^ syntax error
```

code is below

```
 thres=$( RE="$col_null_patt" 
           awk  -v m="$col_start" -v p="$col_len" 
           'BEGIN {n= ENVIRON["RE"]} 
            c=substr($0,m,p);
            if(NR >1 && c ~ "^" n "$"{N++} END{print N+0}' "$cp_input")
```

Comment: `m` was supposed to be start position, but then you reassign `RE` to it in the begin block and then your susbsr() used that wrongly. where do you use substr() result at all? what is `$n` nowhere it uses or sets. what you want to do? count empty(including only whitespaces) lines? then just do with `grep -c '^[\t ]*$'`. your awk should be `RE="$col_null_patt" 
    awk -v strt="$col_start" -v len="$col_len" 
        'BEGIN { rgx = ENVIRON["RE"] } 
              { str=substr($0, strt, len);  if(NR >1 && $n ~ "^" rgx "$") N++ } 
 END{ print N+0 }' "$cp_input"` but IDK what this will do for you.

Comment: Thanku I understood the issue. I edited the code  in the question. Hopefully this will work

Comment: OK, hope it will work, but what that is supposed to be and do?  are you going to count empty columns now? then it will fail in many cases (one would be conservative empty columns will count only 1 and many other issues too). where is your sample input and expected output? what is the problem/question now? please [edit] again and feedback these

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
thres=$(
  RE="$col_null_patt" awk -v m="$col_start" -v p="$col_len" '
    # condition                action
    BEGIN                      {re = ENVIRON["RE"]} 
                               {c = substr($0,m,p)}
    NR > 1 && c ~ "^(" re ")$" {N++}
    END                        {print N+0}
    ' < "$cp_input"
)
```

- You need `VAR=value awk...` for a `VAR` environment variable to be passed to `awk`. With `VAR=value␤awk`, you're just defining a `$VAR` shell variable and then calling `awk` (and the `VAR` will only be in `awk`'s environment if it has been exported beforehand)
- Remember statements in `awk` follow the `condition { action }` pattern. If you want `c=substr($0,m,p)` to be executed for every input record, you need to put it in an action part with a condition part the evaluates to true or without a condition part.

In any case, note that `\s` (to mean any one whitespace character) is not standard and understood by very few awk implementations. `col_null_patt='[[:space:]]'` would be standard and more portable. Or `col_null_patt='[[:space:]]*'` to match any amount (including null) of whitespace.